# Counting instances of a certain character in a string using recursion

Tags: python, function, recursion

This question showed up on my midterm and I realized that I didn't do it right, so I'd like to know where I went wrong.

I am trying to define a function `count_char(string, char)` that returns the total number of times char is in hello by using recursion.

```py
def count_char(string, char):
    #base case:
    if len(string) < 1:
        return
    #recursive case:
    if string[-1] == char:
        total = count_char(string[0:len(string)-1], char) + 1
    return total
```

When I run `count_char("hello", "h")`, I get an error:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'total' referenced before assignment

I'm not sure how else I would go about it so that total isn't a local variable.

Comment: You're using the function `count_char()` inside himself.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the error, if `char` is not in the string then `total` won't have been defined yet. Another thing you should consider is the case where the string is empty, in which case you want to return 0 such that it can propagate back up the recursion stack.

Consider this amended code:

```
def count_char(string, char):
    #base case:
    if len(string) < 1:
        return 0
    #recursive case:
    if string[-1] == char:
        return count_char(string[0:len(string)-1], char) + 1
    return count_char(string[0:len(string)-1], char)
```

Answer (score 0):

As Carcigenicate said, the problem arises because the `if` condition is not guaranteed to be true, and inside the `if` is the only place in the function where `total` is declared and defined.

Here's an alternative way of doing this:

```py
def count_char(string, char):
    #base case:
    if len(string) is 0:
        return 0
    #recursive case:
    total = int(string[-1] == char) + count_char(string[:-1], char)
    return total
```

Also, it's more consistent to return an `int` from both the base case and recursive case.